# How to pass user id or username in url after login form submit in django

Tags: python, django, forms, url

My default project folder is **startup** with **login app** in it.

login app **urls.py**:-

```
url(r'^$', views.LoginFormView.as_view(), name='index'),
```

url to login page.

inside Login app **views.py**:

```
LoginFormView(TemplateView):
         ..........
         .........
        if user is not None:
        if user.is_active:
            login(request, user)
            # messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, 'Login Successfull.')
            return redirect('indexClient')
```

login form submitted and redirect to user profile page.

startup **urls.py**:-

```
url(r'^client/', views.IndexClientView.as_view(), name='indexClient'),
```

startup **views.py**:-

```
class IndexClientView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'startup/index-client.html'
```

I need the url to replace **client** with **username** entered in login form.

Comment: Maybe return an HTTP response instead of redirect and handle the redirect in the front end where the login is being performed?

Answer (score 0):

urls.py:-

```
url(r'^client/(?P<slug>[\w.@+-]+)/$', views.IndexClientView.as_view(), name='indexClient')
```

views.py:-

```
class IndexClientView(TemplateView):
    model=User
    slug_field = "username"
    template_name = 'startup/index-client.html'
```

Now You can access it by :-

```
client/Space/
```

The slug parameter is being used by the DetailView (or any other SingleObjectMixin-based view) to find the object on `User.username` by the use of `model = User` and `slug_field = "username".`

Answer (score 0):

You could import HttpResponseRedirect and make use of reverse function.

Then you views.py would look like this,

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

class LoginFormView(TemplateView):
    ..,...................
    if user is not None:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request, user)
                # messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, 'Login Successfull.')
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('indexClient', kwargs={'username':user.username}))
```

Change your urls.py accordingly,

```
url(r'^login/$', views.LoginFormView.as_view(), name='login'),
url(r'^(?P<username>[\w]+)/$', views.IndexClientView.as_view(), name='indexClient')
```

You would have a login view, and a separate user profile view. Here indexClient is shown as user profile view. After login, django redirects to indexClient view, with username = user.username, ie, username of current user, which should be on the url as you required.

Hope this is useful.